# In the RdlcReport, how to set the Grouping to the Text Box along with the Tablix

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, rdlc

Mine is a single page RDLC report with Header, Body and footer.
I the body there is one Tablix with grouping w.r.t a property in the dataset and I have set the group to the rows in the Tablix and have checked the option "Between each instance of a group" in Page Break Options,
along with this I have a text box with an expression of a value in the dataset.

Ex: An employee report with his personal details(Name, DOB, SEX, Experience, Salary) in the Tablix and EmployeeID in the Text box.

Now in the Dataset we have records of 5 employees.
The outcome of the report is 5 pages of report with Header, Body and footer
and In the body of each page the Tabix is repeated printing all the 5 records one after the other, but  the Text Box with Employee ID (which is above the Tablix)is printed only once in the in the first page. I require Text Box also to be printed with the Employee ID in all the Pages.

What would be the absolute resolution for this scenario in the RDLC Report?

I have developed this requirement in my Visual Studio 2012 MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

Try Grouping feature.
For more details look here - 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/767067/RDLC-Report-Grouping-with-Page-Break-Table-Header